# Cors Policy Problem in a React + Spring Boot Server

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, server

I have made a Spring Boot App for a project which i host it on a raspberry pi 4. The spring works fine on the rpi and then i put the frontend of the project which is made in React. I use nginx to be able to render my react app. The problem is that when i am in browser on the authentication page of react, it throws a cors policy error. I provide you the code below to try to find a solution. The spring boot app works on port 8080\9090 and the react app on the port 3000.

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.111:8080/iotify/auth/authenticate' from origin 'http://192.168.0.111:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:251 
        
        
        POST http://192.168.0.111:8080/iotify/auth/authenticate net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
Vs @ dispatchRequest.js:51
value @ Axios.js:148
(anonymous) @ Axios.js:187
(anonymous) @ bind.js:5
(anonymous) @ useAuthenticate.js:13
c @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69
St @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
o @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
(anonymous) @ useAuthenticate.js:11
(anonymous) @ AuthenticateComponent.js:28
c @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69
St @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
o @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
(anonymous) @ AuthenticateComponent.js:25
Ne @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
He @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:55
Fr @ react-dom.production.min.js:105
zr @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
cu @ react-dom.production.min.js:274
De @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
Vr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109
$t @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:73
useAuthenticate.js:16  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
    at useAuthenticate.js:16:37
    at c (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.throw (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at St (asyncToGenerator.js:3:20)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
```

SecurityConfiguration class

```
package com.daian.iotify.config;

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CsrfConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(@NonNull HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                    var corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://192.168.0.111:3000");
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
                    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
                    return corsConfiguration;
                }))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/iotify/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

AuthenticationController class

```
package com.daian.iotify.auth;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/iotify/auth")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.0.111:3000")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest request){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(request));
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticate(request));
    }
}
```

A custom hook in react to authenticate

```
import App, { AppContext } from '../App';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const useAuthenticate = () => {

    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const { ip } = useContext(AppContext);

    const authenticate = async (authenticateData) => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.post(`http://${ip}/iotify/auth/authenticate`, authenticateData);
            return response.data.token;
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response.status);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return { authenticate, error };
};

export default useAuthenticate;
```

The configuration file for the server on the raspberry pi at location /etc/nginx/sites-available/192.168.0.111

```
server {
        listen 3000;
        listen [::]:3000;

        root /var/www/192.168.0.111;
        index index.html;

        location /var/www/192.168.0.111 {
             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://192.168.0.111:8080/' ;
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, OPTIONS';
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization';
               add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
               add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
               add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
               return 204;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'POST') {
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Orignin' 'http://192.168.0.111:8080/' ;
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
               add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Authorization';
               add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
             }

        }
}
```